# How to get Yes or No, From JSF to VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, jsf

I have a  VB.Net program codes like this:

```
htmlBtnSave = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("f:buttonRSave")
```

that sends some data to a web server. After Onclick event the web site shows a dialogbox which JSF codes like this:

```
hX_6.addBehavior("f:buttonRSave", "onclick", new 
hX_6.JSFBehaviorGeneric("action:confirm","target:Want to save it?"));
```

And the web server asks a question by using the codes upon.

How can my program catch, which button the user clicks on web diaologbox:  Yes or no button.

Comment: `How can my program detect,if the user prefers yes or no.`, what have you tried? Code above does not reflect what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Usually with a message box, its 'DialogResult.Yes' or 'DialogResult.No'.

Comment: I do not ask "yes" or "no" on my program. The web site asks by using JSF. And i want to catch if it is "yes" or "no".